# I no longer view online equations at RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, inline, equation, preview

I've been working on a document for some time and I was normally viewing latex equations in the R Markdown environment with `$Spr = i_ {apl} - i_ {cap}$` as `$$Spr = i_ {apl} - i_ {cap}$$`. But suddenly he stopped visualizing.

I have already adjusted the settings for viewing and I still can't.

`$Spr = i_ {apl} - i_ {cap}$`

`$$Spr = i_ {apl} - i_ {cap}$$`

I can't see either in line or in poup-up

Visualization has been unstable for some time, but then stopped completely.

I suspect it occurred after some package updates.

Could someone help me with this issue.enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JCIT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZORTJ.png)

Comment: I mean in R Markdown

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's solution did not work for me. I performed a complete uninstallation (completely removed all the orphan files and settings) of RStudio and then re-installed it (after a restart) on Mac (OS Ventura 13.5). This did the job.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up a clean Rmarkdown file in a new project. I used your code in a plain Rmarkdown template and the equation looked good to go.
[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. I get it by cleaning the history.